# zipping a folder not working in php

Tags: php, zip

I have created a script to upload a photo and place different sizes versions into a folder. After that, I want to zip that folder. The script is doing all the work I want except zipping the files. No error is showing up.

Here's the code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['upload_time']=time();




$target_dir = 'downloads/'.$_FILES['userImage']["name"].'-'.$_SESSION['upload_time'].'/';


    if(!is_dir($target_dir)){
        mkdir($target_dir);
    }

$file4 = file_get_contents('assets/sizes.txt', true);
$data4=json_decode($file4,true);
foreach($data4 as $data){

    $data=explode('_',$data);
    $data1= preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$data[0]);
    $data2= preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$data[1]);

///uploading photo and creating its different sizes
store_uploaded_image('userImage',$data1,$data2,$data1.'x'.$data2 ,$target_dir);
}



$zip = new ZipArchive();

// open archive 
if ($zip->open('my-archive.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
    die ("Could not open archive");
}

// initialize an iterator
// pass it the directory to be processed
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($target_dir));

// iterate over the directory
// add each file found to the archive
foreach ($iterator as $key=>$value) {
    $zip->addFile(realpath($key), $key) or die ("ERROR: Could not add file: $key");
}

// close and save archive
$zip->close();
echo "Archive created successfully.";
```

Comment: what you get in $key value?

Comment: you want to zip $target_dir folder or dynamic images.?

Comment: whole folder in which images are stored..

Comment: you want to zip downloads folder right?

Comment: no, not the downloads folder..but the folder which is created inside it dynamically and that contains the images.

Comment: and try the below code for zip creation.

Comment: this is the directory in which images are stored `$target_dir = 'downloads/'.$_FILES['userImage']["name"].'-'.$_SESSION['upload_time'].'/';`

Comment: no, it is not working

Comment: tel me $target_dir name?

Comment: In function Zip($source, $destination) what you have given in $source value?

Comment: whenever a  image is uploaded new folder is created which contains the images, and i want to zip that folder. and that folder is named as `$_FILES['userImage']["name"].'-'.$_SESSION['upload_time'].'/'` because i am creating it dynamically

Comment: in `$source` am giving $target_dir value

Comment: please check the code again, it will be clear to you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,For Local systems you can use this code for zip the specific folders.

**Code:-**

```
<?php

function Zip($source, $destination)
{

echo "called function";
    if (!extension_loaded('zip') || !file_exists($source)) {
        return false;
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    if (!$zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    $source = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($source));

    if (is_dir($source) === true)
    {
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $file);

            // Ignore "." and ".." folders
            if( in_array(substr($file, strrpos($file, '/')+1), array('.', '..')) )
                continue;

            $file = realpath($file);

            if (is_dir($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));
            }
            else if (is_file($file) === true)
            {
                $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
            }
        }
    }
    else if (is_file($source) === true)
    {
        $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
    }

    return $zip->close();
}

Zip('/downloads','/my-archive.zip',true);

?>
```

Hope this helps.